# psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

I have an issue with **`TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update`** while updating the table.I'm using postgres with odoo V13, the issue occurs while updating the pool with specific record set and context using **`write()`** method.I'm migrating the code from **`odoo v7 to v13`** I could see the same works in odoo V7 with no issues. I see no syntax errors but still i get this. I just want to understand is this a bug in the version or related to the concurrence of any data ?

I have a following line of code which is part of the one function.
`self.env.get('pk.status').browse(pk_id).with_context(audit_log=True).write(update_vals)`

I have a model named `pk.status` and it has attribute `write(self,update_vals)`, based on conditions it will have to run `x1(update_vals)` as below.

```
def x1(self,update_vals):

    product_pool = self.env.get('pk.product')
    if update_vals:
        if isinstance(update_vals, int):
            update_vals = [update_vals]
        for bs_obj in self.browse(update_vals).read(['End_Date']):
            product_ids = product_pool.search([('id_pk_status', '=', bs_obj['id']),
                                                                         ('is_active', '=', 'Y')])
            if product_ids:
                end_date = bs_obj['End_Date'] or date.today()
                force_update = self._context.get('force_update', False)
                product_ids.with_context(audit_log=True,force_update=force_update).write(
                    {'is_active': 'N', 'end_date': end_date})
```

`Product_ids` record set has a `write(self, val)` function for `'pk.product'` model.
As part of the write() and its conditions will execute x2()

```
def x2(self, vals, condition=None):

    try:
        status_pool = self.env.get('pk.status')
        product_pool = self.env.get('pk.product')
        result = False
        status_obj = status_pool.browse(vals['id_pk_status']).read()[0]
        product_obj = product_pool.browse(vals['id_pk_product']).read()[0]
        if not product_obj['end_date']:
            product_obj['end_date'] = date.today()
        extra_check = True
        if condition:
            statuses = (status_obj['Is_Active'], product_obj['is_active'])
            extra_check = statuses in condition
        if extra_check:
            result = True
            if isinstance(vals['start_date'], str):
                vals['start_date'] = datetime.strptime(vals['start_date'], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
            if not (result and vals['start_date'] >= status_obj['Start_Date']):
                result = False
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
    return result
```

The error occurs while executing the line

`status_obj = status_pool.browse(vals['id_pk_status]).read()[0]`

**Complete Error:**

```
2020-08-09 15:39:11,303 4224 ERROR ek_openerp_dev odoo.sql_db: bad query: UPDATE "pk_status" SET "Is_Active"='N',"write_uid"=1,"write_date"=(now() at time zone 'UTC') WHERE id IN (283150)
ERROR: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/current/addons/models/pk_product.py", line 141, in x2()
    status_obj = status_pool.browse(vals['id_pk_status']).read()[0]
  File "/current/core/addons/nest_migration_utils/helpers/old_cr.py", line 51, in old_cursor
    result = method(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2893, in read
    self._read(stored_fields)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 2953, in _read
    self.flush(fields, self)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5419, in flush
    process(self.env[model_name], id_vals)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 5374, in process
    recs._write(vals)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/models.py", line 3619, in _write
    cr.execute(query, params + [sub_ids])
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 163, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/current/odoo/odoo/sql_db.py", line 240, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
psycopg2.extensions.TransactionRollbackError: could not serialize access due to concurrent update
```

I assume the concurrence in the error states that im doing two write operations in a single thread but im not sure about it. Hope this helps.

Comment: You need to provide the code that causes the error otherwise this question is not going anywhere.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I have added the code with complete details about the error

Comment: What I see is: ```status_pool.browse(vals['id_pk_status]).read()[0]```. In particular a missing ' for  quoting ```id_pk_status```.

Comment: Its my miss during the edit. But in my code quotes are good and thats not at all the issue. i just want to know what the error states.

Answer (score 1):

Each subprocess needs to have a global connection to the database. If you are using `Pool` then you can define a function that creates a global connection and a cursor and pass it to the `initializer` parameter. If you are instead using a `Process` object then I'd recommend you create a single connection and pass the data via queues or pipes.

Like Klaver said, it would be better if you were to provide code so as to get a more accurate answer.

Comment: @Sebastain  I have added the code with complete details about the error

Answer (score 0):

This happens if the transaction level is set to serializable and two processes are trying to update the same column values.

If your choice is to go with serializable isolation level, then you have to rollback and retry the transaction again.